# What is the best way in C# (windows10) to similar dos prompt command "tftp 192.168.x.x put c:\x.bin"

Tags: windows-10, tftp

What is the best way in C# (windows10) to similar dos prompt command "tftp 192.168.x.x put c:\x.bin"
I already doing it ProcessStartInfo but it doesn't work in Windows 10...

Comment: do you have "TFTP Client" windows feature turned on, by the way?

Comment: yes, command working on DOS prompt already.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:
[A simple TFTP client using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19314/A-simple-TFTP-client-using-C)

Also, check the Tftp.Net library - https://tftp4net.codeplex.com/

Comment: I used first one but when I call this library's tftp put, it is passing this line in 1 sec. normal in DOS promt it is wating for 10 seconds to download. 
After execution of this line in code I am breaking the application on next line and I am sending same command from DOS too but then DOS prompt also dosent work. If I break the code before sending this library's put function and I am running DOS prompt command the DOS promt command sending it sucessfully. Probably Windows10 has difference according to Windows7...